# Linear Algebra 3x3 matrix diagonalization Row operation before inversing

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Hello I am diagonalizing the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues I found are $-3$ and $3$. The eigenvectors are 
$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
respectively. My question is: Is it alright to transform the matrix from this
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ to this
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -4 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ to make the inversion process easier? For the equation $D = P^{-1}AP$ ?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Hint. If you multiply an eigenvector by a (nonzero) scalar do you still have an eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your matrix is one that has the eigenvectors as its columns (though not in the order you listed them; beware that this will imply that eigenvalues in the diagonal form will be permuted correspondingly). What you then did is multiply the *first* coordinate of each eigenvector by $2$ to remove the fractions. That is **not** a valid operation; an eigenvector will only remain an eigenvector (for the same eigenvalue) if you multiply the *entire* vecto by a nonzero scalar. So it would have been allowed to multiply each column by a nonzero scalar (and it could be a different scalar for each column if you like), but it is not right to multiply some *row)* by a scalar.

By the way, if you are inverting this matrix just to find the diagonal form, then that is not necessary in the first place. Once you've found a basis of eigenvectors, you *know* that a change of basis to that basis will make the matrix diagonal, with the eigenvalues (in the order they occur in the basis) as diagonal entries.